# Show message as sent/received in other users window with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a prototype chat app in react that I can currently show sent messages in both viewers windows (Agent and User). However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to only show a sent message as sent in one window and received in the other and vice versa. So if the Agent sends a message, it will show with their name and the message in both windows. I'm thinking I need to pass the "author" into each "User messages" and "Agent messages" within App.js, but this doesn't work.

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: []
    }
    this.handleNewMessage = this.handleNewMessage.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
  }

  handleNewMessage = (text) => {
    this.setState({
      messages: [...this.state.messages, { me: true, author: "Me", body: text},{ me: true, author: "Agent", body: text}]
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="agentWindow">
          <Agent messages={this.state.messages} handleNewMessage={this.handleNewMessage} />
        </div>
        <div className="userWindow">
          <User messages={this.state.messages} handleNewMessage={this.handleNewMessage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Agent.js**(User.js is the same)

```
class Agent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Agent">
        <header>
          <p>Agent</p>
        </header>
        <MessageList messages={this.props.messages} />
        <MessageForm onMessageSend={this.props.handleNewMessage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Message.js**

```
class Message extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    author: PropTypes.string,
    body: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    me: PropTypes.bool
  }

  render() {
    const classes = classNames('Message', {
      log: !this.props.author,
      me: this.props.me
    })

    return (
      <div className={classes}>
        {this.props.author && (
          <span className="author">{this.props.author}:</span>
        )}
        {this.props.body}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**MessageList.js**

```
class MessageList extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    messages: [],
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.node.scrollTop = this.node.scrollHeight
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="MessageList" ref={(node) => (this.node = node)}>
        {this.props.messages && this.props.messages.map((message, i) => (
            <Message key={i} {...message} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**MessageForm.js**

```
class MessageForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onMessageSend: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.input.focus()
  }

  handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.onMessageSend(this.input.value)
    this.input.value = ""
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="MessageForm" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <input
            type="text"
            ref={(node) => (this.input = node)}
            placeholder="Enter Message..."
          />
        </div>
        <div className="button-container">
          <button type="submit">
            Send
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Will you put up MessageForm.js pls?

Comment: @RandyCasburn - I've added MessageForm.js to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your explanation...revising my answer. Please h/o.

OK. You are on the right track.  Here is the solution I think you are looking for:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jz6o9y5n7v

Only a few changes. On the form, I added the "source" prop and pass that through to your handler in the App component. That correctly sets the Author prop to the source sent in from the form. I removed the second data element from the messages array. All this gives you the output I think you are after.

Thanks for the opportunity to help with this.

Comment: Do I need to move my `handleNewMessage` in App.js to a separate component?

Comment: Yes, it looks that way. You don't need to do this in a component, a plain JS Obj constructor could handle this. Just make sure the {handleNewMessage} is in scope on your components.

Comment: not sure the best way to setup the constructor in the App.js to handle consolidation of the messages array. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting classnames module to work. Trying to work up a sample to show sharing data between Agent and User.  Essentially, each of these pushes message up to a parent, then parent can provide data to each component. If I can get the REPL to work I'll let you know.

Comment: You should be able to run `npm install classnames` and then import it with `import classNames from 'classnames'` in message.js

Comment: All set, please check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and clear explanation, I understand the solution!

Comment: awesome. glad to help.